# Install (Or suggest to) missing imported Python modules on VS Code like PyCharm does

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

When we import a module that isn't currently installed on the Python used on the current environment, PyCharm suggest us to 'install missing module', if you click install, it'll install it automatically...

Is there any plugin for vscode that does that or something like that?
I want to import `emoji` for example, and like pycharm does, suggest me to install the missing module, so I won't have to do manually a pip install

Is there a plugin that does this for vscode?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your request is already ongoing on `vscode-python` extension:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8062

I suggest to follow this issue to see when it's ready for production.

Comment: Thanks you... I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this feature doesn't exist as of now.

This request has been long outstanding but not considered a priority.